# Graylog stream rule with application running on docker

Tags: docker, graylog

I have an application that running on a docker container, and logs to our Graylog server, however, the Graylog source field is actually the container ID:

```
source
97c0212d3d75
```

Since the container ID changes frequently, I cannot apply the source to the stream rules.

I had a look at the message and seems like there is nothing much I can rely on to create stream rules for this application:

[image]

Can someone please share some experience on this case? My problem here is that I cannot identify the application nor environment.

I am looking for ideas like:

1. Is there a way to make container id static (prob not)
2. Is there a way to send more information to graylog without making code changes or making code to specify the specific values
3. Any better ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised I can set the hostname to my docker containers, so just by adding the following to my docker-compose file should work

```
hostname: billing-rq-${ENV_NAME}
```